# How can I sum values in another df based on a condition in both df's in r?

Tags: r, sum

I'm quite new to R, but I cant find the right way to solve my problem.

I have two df's: one on session level and one on client level. In the client level df I want to sum the number of sessions done by a client in the session df.

The df's look like:

```
          df1                                df2
Sessionid     Client id                    Clientid     
   1              1                           1                 
   2              1                           2                 
   3              2                  
   4              2                  
   5              2
```

I want output like:

```
          df1                                df2
Sessionid     Client id             Clientid     Number_of_sessions
   1              1                    1                 2
   2              1                    2                 3
   3              2                  
   4              2                  
   5              2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `dplyr` library:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Clientid) %>%
  summarise(Number_of_sessions = n())

# Clientid Number_of_sessions
# <int>              <int>
# 1        1           2
# 2        2           3
```

or

```
aggregate(Sessionid ~ Clientid, df, length)
```

which returns the same thing.

Data:

```
structure(list(Sessionid = 1:5, Clientid = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L)) -> df
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
count(group_by(df1, `Client id`), name = "Number_of_sessions")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Groups:   Client id [2]
#>   `Client id` Number_of_sessions
#>         <int>              <int>
#> 1           1                  2
#> 2           2                  3
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R solution would be

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(table(df1$Clientid))
names(df2) <- c("Clientid", "Number_of_sessions")
```

Output

```
#   Clientid Number_of_sessions
# 1        1                  2
# 2        2                  3
```

Comment: To make it a data frame use `as.data.frame(table(df$Clientid))`

Comment: Correct, I edit my answer. Thanks